# When uploading a GLB file onto a website it applies a nonexisting gradient over the whole view

Tags: 3d, blender, babylonjs

I created a model in Blender and when viewing it in Sandbox theres is no gradient when i look at the views set up by the camera, but once the developer adds it to the website a gredient from the bottom of the camera up appears. Anyone know why would that happen? I hope i explained well.

The model in question is a simple food can, with a camera and a few lights.

I tried changing the lighting hoping that was the cause but it changed nothing.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Even though there is not much information about your question like what are you using to deploy the model to website, is it model-viewer or any other rendering method.

Assuming a generic case scenario, the highest probability of why it is happening is because the renderer you are using is automatically assigning materials to the model reasons being,

1. You have not set compatible export options for the model while exporting which can be processed by the renderer.
2. The least viable reason could be that the renderer just did not take the materials/colors/properties because it did not understand them and set its own (I can vouch that the notorious model-viewer does that if you are not careful)

If you can share a link to the website or show how you are using/exporting the model then it could clear out the issues.